# How to create a new project type in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vsx

I've figured out how to create a new *template*, but I need a little more power than that. I need to override what happens when you click the "Run" button for example -- I want it to fire up a development server and then pop open my web browser.

So, how can I add an entirely new project type? And preferably, how can I base it on another project type, such as IronPython?

I know ASP.NET MVC is open source and is quite similar to what I'm trying to do, but I'm not sure if the source I downloaded includes all the VS integration code. Which download should I be looking at?

Answer (score 11):

Here's what I've found so far:

- [Download: Visual Studio 2010 SDK](https://web.archive.org/web/20110508091414/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305CF4-2BEA-43C0-91CD-1B853602DCC5) -- You need this to create a VSPackage (File > New Project > Other Project Types > Extensibility > Visual Studio Package)
- [Tutorial: A Simple Managed Project System](https://web.archive.org/web/20150720032117/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vsxue/archive/2008/03/12/tutorial-a-simple-managed-project-system.aspx)
- [MSDN: Project Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/extensibility/internals/project-types?view=vs-2015)

  - [MSDN: Project Subtypes](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55984)
- [Getting Started with Extending Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ae3cxw0w%28v=vs.100%29)

  - [Visual Studio SDK Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ae3cxw0w%28v=vs.100%29)

    - [Walkthrough: Part 1 - Creating a Basic Project System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/cc512961%28v=vs.100%29)
    - [Walkthrough: Part 2 - Creating a Basic Project System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/cc826178%28v=vs.100%29)

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is create a project subtype / flavor.  It will give you the control you need to customize this and other actions.  But it is a fairly involved process that can't really be summed up in a SO answer box.  But here's the main documentation page on the subject

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb166488(v=VS.80).aspx

Please do post back with any road blocks you hit.

Comment: I need to create a new project type , not a subtype